# How to use keyboard shortcuts like Alt+D, E in Linux?

Tags: kde-plasma

In KDE, for example, to switch to desktop editing mode, you need to press the keyboard shortcut `Alt+D, E`, but no matter how much I try, nothing happens.

I tried to press this strange `Alt+D, E` in all ways and in all sequences, but still nothing happens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of such shortcuts are documented here: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/plasma-desktop/plasma-desktop/shortcuts.html

I cannot see <kbd>Atl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> there. But when I right click on the desktop, I see it is assigned for entering editing mode.

You hit it the following way:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- press <kbd>D</kbd>
- release <kbd>D</kbd>
- release <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- press <kbd>E</kbd>
- release <kbd>E</kbd>

It even works for me when I wait several seconds after Alt + D.